# Conditional template tags for WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having trouble creating a template that displays some content conditionally. This is for a blog that features articles and tutorials. The tutorials will begin with a box containing additional info about the tutorial. The extra info is entered in custom fields.

In my "single.php" file, I have the following code:

```
<section class="entry-content group">
    <?php if ( in_category('tutorials') ) { echo '
        <div class="tutorial-info-box group">
            <h5>About This Tutorial</h5>
            <ul class="tutorial-stats">
                <li> <span> Difficulty: </span> </li>
                <li> <span> Prerequisites: </span> </li>
                <li> <span> Time required: </span> </li>
                <li> <span> Will improve your knowledge of: </span> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    '; } ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</section>
```

The above works fine for rendering this box only on posts in the 'tutorials' category. I'm running into trouble when I try to include the data from the custom fields like so:

```
<section class="entry-content group">
    <?php if ( in_category('tutorials') ) { echo '
        <div class="tutorial-info-box group">
            <h5>About This Tutorial</h5>
            <ul class="tutorial-stats">
                <li> 
                    <span> Difficulty: </span>
                    <?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'difficulty', true ); ?> 
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <span> Prerequisites: </span>
                    <?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'prerequisites', true ); ?>  
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <span> Time required: </span> 
                    <?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'time', true ); ?>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <span> Will improve your knowledge of: </span>
                    <?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'improve', true ); ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    '; } ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</section>
```

I end up with just a blank white screen. I'm assuming this is some kind of syntax error, but I can't figure out what it is. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your including a open `<?php` within a string. Correct it to:

```
<section class="entry-content group">
    <?php if ( in_category('tutorials') ): ?>
        <div class="tutorial-info-box group">
            <h5>About This Tutorial</h5>
            <ul class="tutorial-stats">
                <li> 
                    <span> Difficulty: </span>
                    <?php echo  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'difficulty', true ); ?> 
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <span> Prerequisites: </span>
                    <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'prerequisites', true ); ?>  
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <span> Time required: </span> 
                    <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'time', true ); ?>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <span> Will improve your knowledge of: </span>
                    <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'improve', true ); ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! It's working perfectly now. So, for future reference, should I use a colon after an "if" statement instead of curly braces in order to escape PHP for situations like this?

Comment: No you don't have too. Its just neater in situations where you have more HTML than PHP.